# How do I find mushroom biomes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft's mushroom biome sounds like a pleasant place: Food in abundant supply, and zero hostile mob spawns.

However, in all my time playing, I've never ever found one. Is there a trick to finding them, or do you just have to get lucky?

Comment: There's a site, http://www.minecraftseeds.info/ people post the seeds they find that are unique or just really fun. They have a couple mushroom biomes.

Comment: Another seed that will put you close to a mushroom biome is simply `4`. The biome is located close to spawn, at X=450, Z=-520. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSGXv8u3-8s

Comment: I JUST found one on my world, which i started 2 years ago. It is barely an island, considering land is very close to it. My world is 8000x13000, so you may have to search for quite awhile before you find one. I honestly didnt even know they spawn on every seed, i found mine completely by accident xD. Good luck!

Comment: seed: 7239862655456688312 mushrooms near: +128, +64, +2500 The mushroom peninsula is attached to an icy plains biome.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's important to realize that mushroom biomes only spawn as islands in the middle of oceans.

So, if you want to look for one in a world that doesn't spawn you in one, you can't go walking to find one, you need to find an ocean, make a boat, and search the ocean for a mushroom island.

I can't offer any personal experience of how easy it is to find one by that approach (I've no idea whether most oceans contain one, more than one, or just have a chance of containing one).

Answer (score 11):

I'm afraid you have to get lucky. Your best bet is to start a world with a seed that spawns in a mushroom biome, e.g. `lost`.

...or swim for a *long* time until you find one.

Comment: [infq](http://www.minecraftseeds.info/2012/01/infq.html) is also a nice seed

Answer (score 3):

Install the planes mod, build a p-51 with a radial engine, and have fun exploring almost faster than the map can load/generate. This should make locating mushroom biomes a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not bragging, I was really lucky. In my Legit survival world I found a mushroom biome. And here are some of my tips to find them:

1. Scout the Ocean. Make sure that the ocean is big and don't go next to the coast line, just keep the coastline visible in the corner of your eye.
2. Scout all coast lines of your map. Since oceans are pretty much endless, you can walk on the beaches until you find one that is connected to your beach (worked for me)
3. Use a seed with one either near, or in the map near spawn.

Answer (score 1):

Mobs cannot spawn on mycelium and the best way to find one is to make a boat and explore out in the middle of nowhere, kind of like finding diamonds.

Answer (score 1):

The best "out of game" means I've found for identifying mushroom islands (and any other feature for that matter) is to use the [third party tool AMIDST](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/626786-/).

Before version 1.7.2 mushroom islands were extremely rare.  (I haven't explored much in 1.7.2 yet, to know how that has changed.)

Answer (score 0):

Not actually a biome location answer:

Mycelium spreads on dirt much like grass; if you're playing in SMP with the /give command (or other some other use of a inventory editor), you could give yourself Mycelium and simulate your own biome that way.

It wouldn't be a perfect recreation of Mushroom Biome (if you built over a Desert biome, you may not be able to raise huge mushrooms); Mycelium only allows spawning of Mooshrooms, whereas the Biome itself is what causes anti-mob and natural giant mushrooms.***

Comment: Or, without cheating, you could use a silk touch shovel to aquire a mycelium block from a biome (you need to find one first) and set up a mycelium area closer to home.

Comment: Can hostile mobs spawn on mycelium? Or is it strictly the mushroom biome?

Comment: I'm not actually sure - the main town on my private SMP server is built in a mushroom biome and it's safe to walk around at night on the island without lighting it. However, we've had mobs spawn in tunnels under the biome. I'd have to verify that those weren't in Ocean Biome.

Comment: They will not spawn on Mushroom Biomes,but they will spawn on Mycelium. And yes,you are right. The tunnels where they spawned are in the Ocean (or Deep Ocean) biome. Try adding light there to prevent them spawn.